# Fatal error:Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action' not found in BookmarksController.php on line 4

Tags: magento, bookmarks

it shows:
`Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action' not found in .../app/code/local/Magentix/SocialBookmarking/controllers/Adminhtml/BookmarksController.php on line 4`

I check it and find that nothing is in bookmarkscontroller.php.on line 4. What's wrong is it?
and I also check it that the social bookmarket plugin still shows in the front page here.

Original code:

```
<?php

/** http://www.magentix.fr **/

class Magentix_SocialBookmarking_Adminhtml_BookmarksController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action {

    protected function _initAction() {

        $this->loadLayout()

            ->_setActiveMenu('cms/socialbookmarking')

            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));



        return $this;

    }   



    public function indexAction() {

        $this->_initAction()->renderLayout();

    }



    public function editAction() {

        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $model  = Mage::getModel('socialbookmarking/bookmarks')->load($id);



        if ($model->getId() || $id == 0) {

            $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);

            if (!empty($data)) {

                $model->setData($data);

            }



            Mage::register('socialbookmarking_data', $model);



            $this->loadLayout();

            $this->_setActiveMenu('cms/socialbookmarking');



            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));



            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);



            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('socialbookmarking/adminhtml_bookmarks_edit'))

                ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('socialbookmarking/adminhtml_bookmarks_edit_tabs'));



            $this->renderLayout();

        } else {

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('socialbookmarking')->__('Bookmark does not exist'));

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

        }

    }



    public function newAction() {

        $this->_forward('edit');

    }



    public function saveAction() {

        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {



            if(isset($_FILES['bookmarkimage']['name']) && $_FILES['bookmarkimage']['name'] != '') {

                try {

                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('bookmarkimage');



                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));

                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);



                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);



                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'social';

                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['bookmarkimage']['name']);



                } catch (Exception $e) {



                }



                $data['image'] = 'social/'.$_FILES['bookmarkimage']['name'];

            }



            if(isset($data['bookmarkimage']['delete'])) $data['image'] = '';



            $model = Mage::getModel('socialbookmarking/bookmarks');     

            $model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));



            try {

                if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {

                    $model->setCreatedTime(now())->setUpdateTime(now());

                } else {

                    $model->setUpdateTime(now());

                }   



                $model->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('socialbookmarking')->__('Bookmark was successfully saved'));

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);



                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {

                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));

                    return;

                }

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));

                return;

            }

        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('socialbookmarking')->__('Unable to find bookmark to save'));

        $this->_redirect('*/*/');

    }



    public function deleteAction() {

        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {

            try {

                $model = Mage::getModel('socialbookmarking/bookmarks');



                $model->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->delete();



                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('socialbookmarking')->__('Bookmark was successfully deleted'));

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());

                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));

            }

        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/');

    }



    public function massDeleteAction() {

        $socialbookmarkingIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('socialbookmarking');

        if(!is_array($socialbookmarkingIds)) {

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('socialbookmarking')->__('Please select bookmark(s)'));

        } else {

            try {

                foreach ($socialbookmarkingIds as $socialbookmarkingId) {

                    $socialbookmarking = Mage::getModel('socialbookmarking/bookmarks')->load($socialbookmarkingId);

                    $socialbookmarking->delete();

                }

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(

                    Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__(

                        'Total of %d record(s) were successfully deleted', count($socialbookmarkingIds)

                    )

                );

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());

            }

        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');

    }



    public function massStatusAction() {

        $socialbookmarkingIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('socialbookmarking');

        if(!is_array($socialbookmarkingIds)) {

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select bookmark(s)'));

        } else {

            try {

                foreach ($socialbookmarkingIds as $socialbookmarkingId) {

                    $socialbookmarking = Mage::getSingleton('socialbookmarking/bookmarks')

                        ->load($socialbookmarkingId)

                        ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))

                        ->setIsMassupdate(true)

                        ->save();

                }

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(

                    $this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($socialbookmarkingIds))

                );

            } catch (Exception $e) {

                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());

            }

        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/index');

    }



    protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream') {

        $response = $this->getResponse();

        $response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','');

        $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true);

        $response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true);

        $response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; image='.$fileName);

        $response->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'));

        $response->setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');

        $response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content));

        $response->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType);

        $response->setBody($content);

        $response->sendResponse();

        die;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your extended class name is misspelled - `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action` should be `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`.

Comment: Cool.it works now. but I am a little puzzle that I have not modify it before. why it can be changed itself?

Comment: Glad I could help. As for the class name changing by itself, it couldn't have! Probably just a simple typo. I myself have a keyboard shortcut to lowercase variables and I sometimes mash it by mistake :)

Comment: I've had this issue if I do this carelessly and then move from a non-case-sensitive environment locally to a case-sensitive environment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you:

- included the file in bookmarkscontroller.php
- put BookMarksController is in the right place

Comment: Why down vote? You did not post any code when I posted my answer.